# How add hosts from user's input in a ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I need to add a host from the user's input. Now I'm trying to use the ansible `in-memory inventory`, `add_host` module and `prompt` to add the target host to execute the remaining tasks. This is the content of my playbook:

> ### Deploy.yml
>
> ```
> - name: Adding the host server
>   hosts: localhost
>
> - vars_prompt:
>   - name: "Server IP"
>     prompt: "Server"
>     private: no
>
>   - name: "Username (default: Ubuntu)"
>     prompt: "User"
>     default: "Ubuntu"
>     private: no
>
>   - name: "Password"
>     prompt: "Passwd"
>     private: yes
>     encrypt: "sha512_crypt"
>
>   - name: "Identity file path"
>     prompt: "IdFile"
>     private: no
>     when: Passwd is undefined
>
>   tasks:
>     - name: Add host server
>       add_host:
>         name: "{{ Server }}"
>         ansible_ssh_user: "{{ User }}"
>         ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ IdFile }}"
>       when: IdFile is defined
>
>     - name: Add host server
>       add_host:
>         name: "{{ Server }}"
>         ansible_ssh_user: "{{ User }}"
>         ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ Passwd }}"
>       when: Passwd is defined
>
> - hosts: "{{ Server }}"
>
> tasks:
>     - name: Copy the script file to the server
>       copy:
>         src: script.sh
>         dest: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/folder/"
>         mode: 755
>         force: yes
>         attr:
>           - +x
> ```

When I run this playbook with this command `$ ansible-playbook Deploy.yml`, The output is:

```
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [Adding the host server] ***********************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
Server: <server-ip>
User [Ubuntu]:
Passwd:
IdFile: <path/to/id/file>
ERROR! the field 'hosts' is required but was not set
```

I don't know why it throws this error:

```
ERROR! the field 'hosts' is required but was not set
```

How can I do what I need to do?

### UPDATE:

It still not working. This is the content of my playbook:

> ### Deploy.yml
>
> ```
> - name: Adding the host server
>   hosts: localhost
>
>   vars_prompt:
>   - name: "Server"
>     prompt: "Server IP"
>     private: no
>
>   - name: "User"
>     prompt: "Username"
>     default: "Ubuntu"
>     private: no
>
>   - name: "Passwd"
>     prompt: "Password"
>     private: yes
>     encrypt: "sha512_crypt"
>
>   - name: "IdFile"
>     prompt: "Identity file path"
>     private: no
>     when: Passwd is undefined
>
>   tasks:
>     - name: Add host server
>       add_host:
>         name: "{{ Server }}"
>         ansible_ssh_user: "{{ User }}"
>         ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ IdFile }}"
>       when: IdFile is defined
>
>     - name: Add host server
>       add_host:
>         name: "{{ Server }}"
>         ansible_ssh_user: "{{ User }}"
>         ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ Passwd }}"
>       when: IdFile is undefined
>
> - hosts: "{{ Server }}"
>
>   tasks:
>     - name: Copy the script file to the server
>       copy:
>         src: script.sh
>         dest: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/folder/"
>         mode: 755
>         force: yes
>         attr:
>           - +x
> ```

When I run this playbook with this command `$ ansible-playbook Deploy.yml`, The output is:

```
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [Adding the host server] ***********************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
Server IP: <server-ip>
Username [Ubuntu]:
Password:
Identity file path: <path/to/id/file>
ERROR! the field 'hosts' is required but was not set
```

I don't know why it throws this error:

```
ERROR! The field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'Server' is undefined
```

> **Here is a flowchart of how the playbook should works:**
>
> ```
> +------------------+     +---------------+     +-----------------+
> |Use ansible to run|     |Get host IP fom|     |Get ssh User from|
> |  this playbook   +---->+ user's input  +---->+  user's input   |
> +------------------+     +---------------+     +--------+--------+
>                                                         |
>                                                         v
>                                            +------------+--------+
>                                            |Get ssh password from|
>                                            |    user's input     |
>                                            +------------+--------+
>                                                         |
>                                                         v
>                    +---------------+     *************************
>                    |Add a host with| Yes | Did the user inputted |
>         v----------+   password    +<---+|      a password?      |
> +----------------+ +---------------+     ***************+*********
> ||Run some tasks||                                      |No
> ||in recently   ||                                      v
> ||added host    || +---------------+       +------------+--------+
> +----------------+ |Add a host with|       |Get ssh identity file|
>         ^----------+ identity file +<------+  from user's input  |
>                    +---------------+       +---------------------+
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I've updated my answer to suit the changes in your question, with the original answer left for historic reasons.

To solve the substitution error you are seeing, which results in an empty host list in your second play, I would instead use an inventory group.

There are also two other syntax errors in the second play

1. The file mode needs to be octal (i.e. `0700`)
2. The attribute is invalid. My assumption is you are trying to make the file executable, so fix the file mode and remove the attribute.

Here is an updated playbook:

```
- name: Adding the host server
  hosts: localhost

  vars_prompt:
    - name: "Server"
      prompt: "Server IP"
      private: no

    - name: "User"
      prompt: "Username"
      default: "Ubuntu"
      private: no

    - name: "Passwd"
      prompt: "Password"
      private: yes
      encrypt: "sha512_crypt"

    - name: "IdFile"
      prompt: "Identity file path"
      private: no
      when: Passwd is undefined

  tasks:
    - name: Add host server
      add_host:
        name: "{{ Server }}"
        ansible_ssh_user: "{{ User }}"
        ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ IdFile }}"
        group: added_hosts
      when: IdFile is defined

    - name: Add host server
      add_host:
        name: "{{ Server }}"
        ansible_ssh_user: "{{ User }}"
        ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ Passwd }}"
        group: added_hosts
      when: IdFile is undefined

- hosts: added_hosts

  tasks:
    - name: Copy the script file to the server
      copy:
        src: script.sh
        dest: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/folder/"
        mode: 0755
        force: yes
```

=== OLD ANSWER ===

User input is stored in the whatever variable you are using for the `name` attribute in each of the variable prompts.

You need to switch around your `name` and `prompt` values under `vars_prompt`

There are also YAML formatting issues

For example:

```
- vars_prompt:
  - name: "Server IP"
    prompt: "Server"
    private: no
```

should be:

```
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "server"
      prompt: "Server IP"
      private: no
```

Then you can refer to the `{{ server }}` variable in your tasks

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Added an example

Comment: Thanks! I have that tried and it didn't work as expected. It assigns the result to the correct variable and displays the correct message, but it throws the same error. I receive the same error.

Comment: Ah ok.. it's a YAML formatting issue. Remove the `-` from in front of `vars_prompt` and ensure it is indented within the play

Comment: Updated answer to reflect the latest question

Comment: could you please add an example of how you call that playbook indicating the inputs ?

Answer (score 1):

Your ansible script is having a problem.

```
  vars_prompt:
```

remove `-` from `vars_prompt` line it will work properly.

I tried in my local server the same script is working properly.

```
- name: Adding the host server
  hosts: localhost

  vars_prompt:
  - name: "Server"
    prompt: "Server IP"
    private: no

  - name: "User"
    prompt: "Username"
    default: "Ubuntu"
    private: no

  - name: "Passwd"
    prompt: "Password"
    private: yes
    encrypt: "sha512_crypt"

  - name: "IdFile"
    prompt: "Identity file path"
    private: no
    when: Passwd is undefined

  tasks:
    - name: Add host server
      add_host:
        name: "{{ Server }}"
        ansible_ssh_user: "{{ User }}"
        ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ IdFile }}"
      when: IdFile is defined

    - name: Add host server
      add_host:
        name: "{{ Server }}"
        ansible_ssh_user: "{{ User }}"
        ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ Passwd }}"
      when: Passwd is defined

    - name: Create a file
      shell: touch newfile
      delegate_to: "{{ Server }}"
```

In the last task update to your task and run it.

```
    - name: Create a file
      shell: touch newfile
      delegate_to: "{{ Server }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't works as expected. When I execute your example code it throws to me this error: `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "to use the 'ssh' connection type with passwords, you must install the sshpass program"}`. Actually I need to use a Identity File to connecto to my server through `ssh`. I have updated the code, can you check it?

Comment: I understand that I need to install a dependency, but in my test I have input a Identity File path, the password is optional.

Comment: Ok, I have added a flowchart diagram to explain how the playbook should works.